# Why does the Android Debugger's Expression viewer break in horrible and mysterious ways?

Tags: java, android, debugging

Or, when is a REPL not a REPL.

I tried to run

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").defaultCenturyStart)
```

in the Android Studio debugger's Evaluate Expression window -- and it gave me the highly strange error:

> Type mismatch can't assign java.util.Date to java.util.Date

WTF??

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is because the Android Debugger does a whole pile of subtle, complex, fragile and in-reversible transformations of what it extracts from the seething mass of instructions and data on the device, before depositing it in a local JVM. As a consequence of this, daring to actually *execute* methods on the resulting "instances", especially methods which, heaven forfend, might take non-primitives as arguments, is completely beyond the pale, and should not be expected to work.

This is apparently obvious.